# Metadata.getMinimumBalanceForRentExemption seems to return wrong value. | mpl-token-metadata from Metaplex

Tags: javascript, typescript, frontend, web-frontend

I have a question for the createCreateMetadataAccountV2Instruction.
I'm trying to calculate the fee with `Metadata.getMinimumBalanceForRentExemption`
But seems it returns wrong value.
I'm getting this error from the transaction.

`Transfer: insufficient lamports 2491680, need 5616720`

The function returns 1600800 but should be higher.

```
const metadataFee = await Metadata.getMinimumBalanceForRentExemption(
        {
          key: Key.MetadataV1,
          updateAuthority: mintAuthority,
          mint: form.mintAccount?.pubkey,
          data: tokenMetadata,
          primarySaleHappened: true,
          isMutable: true,
          tokenStandard: TokenStandard.Fungible,
          uses: null,
          collection: null,
          editionNonce: 255,
        },
        connection.current
      )
```

Please tell me if the args seem wrong.

Also I tried the `Metadata.biteSize` and it returned 102 but it's actually 679.

https://explorer.solana.com/address/R747jBxHo56wfb7FqVymdQWYpeny16Po6WwmXiiQ9g6?cluster=devnet

How to know the true rent fee?
Please let me know if you know something about this.

Thank you always.
Have a good day!

Comment: I updated mpl-token-metadata to v2.2.1 and add collectionDetails key as null but still returns not enough price.